# How to change the color of a word when it appears more than once

Tags: javascript, regex

I"m currently trying to use a regular expression to change the word "Kanye" to appear in red.

However, it's not showing up:

```
<div id="kanye">
  <center>
    <p>I miss the old Kanye,</p>
         <p> straight from the Go Kanye
<p>Chop up the soul Kanye, set on his goals Kanye</p>
<p>I hate the new Kanye, the bad mood Kanye</p>
<p>The always rude Kanye, spaz in the news Kanye</p>
<p>I miss the sweet Kanye, chop up the beats Kanye</p>
<p>I gotta say, at that time I'd like to meet Kanye</p>
<p>See, I invented Kanye, it wasn't any Kanyes</p>
<p>And now I look and look around and there's so many Kanyes</p>
<p>I even had the pink polo, I thought I was Kanye</p>
<p>What if Kanye made a song about Kanye</p>
<p>Called "I Miss The Old Kanye"? Man, that'd be so Kanye</p>
<p>That's all it was Kanye, we still love Kanye</p>
<p>And I love you like Kanye loves Kanye</p>
 </center>
  </div>
```

Script is below:

```
<script>
var text = document.getElementById("kanye");
var str = kanye.innerHTML;
    reg = /\[Kanyes?|yeezy/ig

var toStr = String(reg);
var color = (toStr.replace('\/g', '|')).substring(1);   


var colors = color.split("|");

if (colors.indexOf("kanye") > -1) {
    str = str.replace(/\[Kk]anyes?/g, '<span style="color:red;">red</span>');
}

document.getElementById("updated").innerHTML = str;

</script>
```

Am I not correctly using the span? Thanks again!

Comment: Does anything have an id of `updated`? I don't see it in your HTML and you are trying to set the innerHTML of that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for your case, also you can check for **Kanyes** in different if case.

```
var text = document.getElementById("kanye");
var str = kanye.innerHTML;
if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("kanye") > -1) {
str = str.replace(/kanyes/ig, '<span style="color:red;">Kanyes</span>');
str = str.replace(/kanye/ig, '<span style="color:red;">Kanye</span>');  
}
document.getElementById("kanye").innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks so much!